# How to disable all network servers in SparkSession

Tags: java, apache-spark

I create a Spark session with:

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
    
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate();;
```

This creates two servers running on the local host:

```
Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 54230.
Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 54231.
```

Is it possible to completely disable these two services and prevent them from starting-up?

I need to create and empty data frame then convert it to Parquet with `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SparkToParquetSchemaConverter`.

Network servers should not be needed for this.